# Minimum number of clicks to turn all the edges on.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

On clicking a node in a tree, all the adjacent edges are turned on. Calculate min of clicks such that all the edges are turned on.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Skipping a level each time but can't figure out something general.

Comment: What about a cyclic graph, or a tree? How many clicks do you need? What about a complete graph? _Try_ a few examples.

Comment: @Arthur: the question is about a tree.

Comment: Oh. Well, then. My last sentence still stands. _Try_ a few examples. See if you can guess the answer.

Comment: I took examples of full binary tree. If levels are even,start from root and skip alternate levels (For 4 level binary tree,5 clicks). For odd level binary tree, start from 2nd level nodes and skip alternate levels (For 3 levels,2 clicks.)

Comment: What about trees that are not binary? Hint: start at (one step in from) a leaf node.

Answer (score 2):

Color your $n$ vertices with two colors such that any two adjacent vertices have different colors (this is possible because your graph is a tree, see [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)). Now click on the vertices of the color you used less then all the edges will turn on. By the [box-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) the number of such vertices is less or equal to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Note that for a [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) (which is a tree), it suffices to click on one vertex at the center, but in general the bound above can not be smaller because the linear graph (which is a tree) with $n$ vertices need at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ clicks.